# Conditional filter with Having in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements, union

I'm using SQL Server 2016. I'm trying to figure out how to conditionally filter with a having clause.

I want to give me a list of all IDs, date, and username that if the date is before 2018 show me that users with 2-12 IDs, if the date is after 2018 then show me the users with 2-24 IDs. I can only think of unioning the codes but that increases the processing time, is there another way to do this quicker?

Original Code:

```
select [id], [date], [user name]
from [table]
where [date] < '2018-01-01' 
group by [id], [date], [user name]
having count([id]) between 2 and 12) b
```

UNION Idea:

```
select [id], [date], [user name]
from [table]
where [date] < '2018-01-01' 
group by [id], [date], [user name]
having count([id]) between 2 and 12) b

UNION 

select [id], [date], [user name]
from [table]
where [date] >= '2018-01-01' 
group by [id], [date], [user name]
having count([id]) between 2 and 24) b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OR in your HAVING statement:

```
select [id], [date], [user name]
from [table]
group by [id], [date], [user name]
having (
        (count([id]) between 2 and 12 AND [date] < '2018-01-01')
        OR
        (count([id]) between 2 and 24 AND [date] >= '2018-01-01')
       );
```

This only works if the columns you are referencing in your HAVING clause are aggregates or included in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Thanksa that worked. I didn't know it was possible to run multiple conditions in the Having Clause